# Использование GPU на MacBook при работе с Machine Learning

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pytorch

Какие есть способы обучения моделей ML на ноутбуках MacBook Pro при использовании GPU на видеокартах Radeon.

В библиотеке torch есть функция использования GPU

```
torch.cuda()
```

Но поскольку это технология Nvidia, работает только для видео карт Nvidia, а в новых маках AMD Radeon Pro.

Поискал в интернете, народ пишет что есть примерно 2 варианта:

1. Использование eGPU
2. Использование сервисов типа: [floydhub.com](https://www.floydhub.com/)

Может кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой и нашел варианты решения без использования сторонних сервисов или оборудования?

Comment: скорость  обучения в большей степени зависит от алгоритма, моделей, и в малой доле зависит от мощности GPU

Comment: @SeniorPomidor сколько вы моделей обучали? 2 штуки? У вам одна и та же модель может в 10 раз быстреё обучаться на более мощной видяхе. Грубо говоря ночь или сходить на обед

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, [попробуйте объяснить это глупым "data scientists", работающим с "deep learning"](https://blog.slavv.com/picking-a-gpu-for-deep-learning-3d4795c273b9) ;-)

Comment: Если даже использовать модель DenseNet-121 на простых примерах, то обучение на CPU занимает ну очень большое количество времени.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow хорошо работает на моем MacBook Pro. Но он НЕ использует GPU.

Сейчас есть несколько альтернативов:

- Использовать Amazon AWS.
- Купить ПК и один или несколько видеокарт nVidia.
- Купить внешнюю видеокарту для MacBook Pro, которая будет стоить дороже(20к+ только за коробку), чем новый комп. Но тут нужен Thunderbolt 3